# Can I precisely position charts in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I am using Google Sheets to create a "Monthly Report" spreadsheet for a product, and am attempting to make an attractive, compelling experience for the consumers of the report.

In this spreadsheet, I have several charts across the top of a tab. Due to the controls for grabbing and resizing a chart, it seems to be impossible to make the charts a uniform size and impossible to place them in a position that lines up with the block of cells the chart describes.

Is there a way precisely to control the size and position of a chart in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been already patched and charts can be nowadays (17.01.2019) moved around and resized with millimetre precision across the whole spreadsheet. Maximum precision of placing can be achieved by holding **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>** key with arrow keys.

---

[image: 1]